# Storing database value into variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table category has these columns:

```
idcategory
categorySubject
users_idusers
```

I have a form with a simple radio buttons and a textbox. 
I have a select all statement for category and need to get the idcategory stored into a variable ($getCatId) so I can use this statement:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO topic(subject, topicDate, users_idusers,     category_idcategory, category_users_idusers) VALUES('($_POST[topic])', '$date', '$_SESSION[userid]', '$getCatId', '$_SESSION[userid]');";
```

What is the best way to get and store categoryid?

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') //show form if not posted
    {   

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM category;";

     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

         ?>
    <form method="post" action="createTopic.php">
        Choose a category:
        </br>
        </br>

        <?php 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<div class= 'choice'><input type='radio' name='category' value='". $row['idcategory'] . "'>" . $row['categorySubject'] ."</div></br>";

        }

               echo 'Topic: <input type="text" name="topic" minlength="3" required>
             </br></br>
             <input type="submit" value="Add Topic" required>
             </form>';

            }


   if ($_POST){
       if(!isset($_SESSION['signedIn']) && $_SESSION['signedIn'] == false)
{

    echo 'You must be signed in to contribute';
}
       else{
         $sql="INSERT INTO topic(subject, topicDate, users_idusers, category_idcategory, category_users_idusers) VALUES('($_POST[topic])', '$date', '$_SESSION[userid]', '$getCatId', '$_SESSION[userid]');"; 

            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            echo "Added!";
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this question correctly, you'll have your `$getCatId` (id of the category) in `$_POST['category']` (after sending form) in your case

Comment: Yes, after the submit button has been pressed, The user chooses from radio buttons that come from the database. I don't know if it matters or not where I put the code but I already have one query there. I wasn't sure if I could put another one in the same section

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is protect yourself from [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) by parameterizing your queries before old [Bobby Tables](https://www.xkcd.com/327/) comes to pay you a visit.

[image: bobby tables]

You might also look into using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as I've demonstrated below because it's a consistent API that works with a lot of different database management systems, so this leads to wonderfully portable code for you. [Here's an annotated working example on Github](https://github.com/scratchers/stackoverflow-q-40444011):

```
<?php

// returns an intance of PDO
// https://github.com/jpuck/qdbp
$pdo = require __DIR__.'/mei_DV59j8_A.pdo.php';

// dummy signin
session_start();
$_SESSION['signedIn'] = true;
$_SESSION['userid'] = 42;

//show form if not posted
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category;";

    // run query
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="createTopic.php">
    Choose a category:
    </br>
    </br>

    <?php
    // get results
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "
            <div class= 'choice'>
                <input type='radio' name='category' value='$row[idcategory]'/>
                $row[categorySubject]
            </div>
            </br>
        ";
    }

    echo '
        Topic: <input type="text" name="topic" minlength="3" required>
        </br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Topic" required>
    </form>
    ';

}


if ($_POST){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['signedIn']) && $_SESSION['signedIn'] == false){
        echo 'You must be signed in to contribute';
    } else {
        // simulate your date input
        $date = date("Y-m-d");

        // bind parameters
        $sql = "
            INSERT INTO topic (
                subject,   topicDate,  users_idusers,  category_idcategory,  category_users_idusers
            ) VALUES(
                :subject, :topicDate, :users_idusers, :category_idcategory, :category_users_idusers
            );
        ";

        // prepare and execute
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute([
            'subject' => "($_POST[topic])",
            'topicDate' => $date,
            'users_idusers' => $_SESSION['userid'],
            // to answer your question, here's your variable
            'category_idcategory' => $_POST['category'],
            'category_users_idusers' => $_SESSION['userid'],
        ]);

        echo "Added!";
    }
}
```